# Tengo un FOR en PHP y necesito que un row me muestre opcion A y el otro row opcion B

Tags: php

tengo una duda.
Acualmente tengo un timeline en html el cual me muestra uno a la derecha y el otro a izquierda, pero lo quiero intener con datos dinamicos.

Para poner a la derecha solo inicio con `<li>`
Pero para ponerlo a la izquierda lo inicion con `<li class="time-inverted">`

Lo que deseo esque el primero me lo ponga a la izquierda y el siguiente a la derecha y asi sucesivamente segun la cantidad que traiga.

Este es mi consulta php:

```
public function historial() {
    $id_activo = $this->input->post('id_activo');
    $historial = $this->stock->historial($id_activo);
    $resp = '';
    foreach ($historial as $row) {

        $resp .= "<ul class='timeline'>
                            <li>
                                <div class='timeline-panel'>
                                    <div class='timeline-heading'>
                                        <h4 class='timeline-title'>" . $row ['nombre_completo'] . "</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><small class='text-muted'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></i> " . $row ['fecha_asignada'] . "</small></p>
                                    <div class='timeline-body'>
                                        <p>" . $row ['tipo'] . " - " . $row ['descripcion'] . "</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>";
    }
    echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

Como ven aqui solo utilizo en `<li>` pero el query me devuelve 2 datos o en otros casos mas datos, no se como poner el segundo parametro en `<li class="time-inverted">` y el que le sigue a la derecha y de esa forma sucesivamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declara una variable boleana de la siguiente forma:

```
$izquierda = true;
```

Finalmente el codigo:

```
public function historial() {
    $id_activo = $this->input->post('id_activo');
    $historial = $this->stock->historial($id_activo);
    $resp = '';
    $izquierda = true;
    foreach ($historial as $row) {

        $resp .= "<ul class='timeline'>";
        if ($izquierda) {
            $resp .= "<li>";
        } else {
            $resp .= "<li class='timeline-inverted'>";
        }
        $izquierda = !$izquierda;
        $resp .= " <div class='timeline-panel'>
                                    <div class='timeline-heading'>
                                        <h4 class='timeline-title'>" . $row ['nombre_completo'] . "</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p><small class='text-muted'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></i> " . $row ['fecha_asignada'] . "</small></p>
                                    <div class='timeline-body'>
                                        <p>" . $row ['tipo'] . " - " . $row ['descripcion'] . "</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>";
    }
    echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

En cada iteracion, cambiamos el valor de $izquierda, de tal forma de saber de que lado se imprime

Comment: Cómo tal la respuesta creo que es la adecuada, pero me atreveria a recomendar que desde el origen de datos se tenga algun parametro para identificar si el elemento va para un lado o para el otro. :)

Comment: no, porque fijate que habla de segun la cantidad de filas que vengan.. o sea, como sabe el origen a donde va a parar cada fila? si hay un filtro o algo, como sabe para que lado va? @M.Gress

Comment: Por eso deberia de existir dentro del origen de datos algun campo que identifique a que lado pertenece, claro que como desconocemos el origen de los datos y su estructura, porque me llama la atención cómo logra que identificar que siempre va a ir uno izquiera y otro derecha. @gbianchi

Comment: Porque el decide que muestra uno a la izquierda y otro a la derecha. me parece que estas pensando mal la idea. es mostrar elementos a izquierda y derecha. no importa como estan en la DB, que no deberia solucionar problemas de vista..

Comment: Si el query devolviera todos los pares. y todos estuvieran "marcados" a izquierda, no se mostrarian uno y otro lado.. solo un lado... Esto esta bien, la vista soluciona los problemas de vista @M.Gress